# TypeError at / 'str' object is not a mapping in django template

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to set up links inside a tags, and when I do this procedure as seen in the code, it gives me the error:

> TypeError at / 'str' object is not a mapping

It use to work fine but then decided not to

template code:

```
<a class="item" href="{% url 'home' %}">
```

urls code:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', include('admin_llda.urls') ),
  path('about/', views.about, name = 'about'),
  path('dashboard/',views.dashboard, name = 'dashboard'),
  path('',views.homepage, name = 'home')   
]
```

Comment: It looks like there is an error in your `homepage` view.

Comment: As you say it worked before, maybe is a problem with the url you try to visit. Anyway try to update your template with: `<a class="item" href="{{ url }}">Home</a>
`

Answer (score 54):

Check that you have properly named the `name` kwarg in your `urls` file.
It's a keyword argument, not an argument. So you should type the keyword and the value.

For example your current `urlpatterns` list in one of your installed apps `urls.py` file looks like this:

```
    urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.index, 'index'),
       path('like/', views.like, 'like')
    ]
```

You should check if you have missed the `name` kwarg. The above code should be changed to:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('like/', views.like, name='like')
    ]
```

If you want to find it faster, you can comment each app's url inclusion, in the `your_project/urls.py` file. When the error is gone, it means that you should check the commented app `urls.py` file.

Answer (score 24):

Check if you have the `name` argument in all of your `urls.py` files, for each Django app you have installed.

If you have specified a name argument for any url in the `path` function, it should be declared like `path('', views.a, name='view.a')`, not like `path('', views.a, 'view.a')`.

Notice **the absence of the `name` argument** in the latter code.
If you miss the name argument, you will get the `'TypeError at / 'str' object is not a mapping'` error.

Comment: path("", ApiRoot.as_view(), name=ApiRoot.name)   .Doesntowork

Comment: url(r'^$',
        ApiRoot.as_view(),
        name=ApiRoot.name),  surprisingly does work....

Answer (score 20):

Please, check for errors in `admin_llda.urls`.
You might have missed adding `name=''` in one of the `path()` calls.

E.g.:

You might have written

```
path('',views.some_method, 'somename')
```

instead of path

```
path('',views.some_method, name= 'somename')
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and I found the solution! Check your urls.py and whether you failed to name any url appropriately- not necessarily

Comment: This answer has been given https://stackoverflow.com/a/55865069/5468463

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , check the  `name` argument in the `path('',,name=" ")`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding namespace to your url
e.g add the following to your 'my_app/urls.py'
`app_name='my_app'`

then your template should look something like: `<a class="item" href="{% url 'my_app:home' %}">`

finally be sure to register your app in the 'my_project/settings.py'

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns