# I am building a webapplication using Django. I have created 3 models in models.py and want to connect the models using templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am building a web application for my college project.I am referring to the Django beginner book where they have built a blog post. I am using this as a reference to build a construction management application. I currently have 3 models as in the image.
[This is a screenshot of my models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTBfk.jpg)

with this I have created class based views and the URLS for them. I want to start a new project from the client details page but i am not able to configure the url properly. I get the error TypeError at /client/1/update/
'str' object is not a mapping

I am stuck and not sure how to proceed further. Please let me know i can share more screenshots for the community.

[This is a screenshot of my models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GM95.jpg)

[and this is my URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt53d.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038467/typeerror-at-str-object-is-not-a-mapping-in-django-template

Comment: Using the Kwarg name = ' ' got my issue resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038467/typeerror-at-str-object-is-not-a-mapping-in-django-template